# What should I know about the Fisher King legends before reading Last Call?

Tags: fault-lines

I've been reading up on the legends of the Fisher King before diving into Tim Powers' Last Call, but I was wondering what I should know about it. It all seems very vague, and different stories tell it differently. Is there a specific story or resource that would help me understand the mythology better than "king gets wounded in the legs or groin, kingdom suffers, knights try to heal him"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as mythology goes, the Fisher King is one of the most well visited well of ideas for stories across the European subcultures. Your synopsis is one of the very basic ideas underlying the myth and can often be enough to follow most stories based on the idea.

The Fisher King inspired works in French, famously "[Perceval, the Story of the Grail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceval,_the_Story_of_the_Grail)", but probably has had origins in early Celtic myths. It is most famously known for its interpretations within the King Arthur mythos and has been reinterpreted numerous times.

Wikipedia's [Fisher King entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_King) gives only a tiny bit of general help:

> The Fisher King, or the Wounded King, figures in Arthurian legend as the latest in a line charged with keeping the Holy Grail. Versions of his story vary widely, but he is always wounded in the legs or groin, and incapable of moving on his own. When he is injured, his kingdom suffers as he does, his impotence affecting the fertility of the land and reducing it to a barren Wasteland. Little is left for him to do but fish in the river near his castle Corbenic. Knights travel from many lands to heal the Fisher King, but only the chosen can accomplish the feat. This is Percival in the earlier stories; in the later versions, he is joined by Galahad and Bors.
>
> Confusingly, many works have two wounded Grail Kings who live in the same castle, a father and son (or grandfather and grandson). The more seriously wounded father stays in the castle, sustained by the Grail alone, while the more active son can meet with guests and go fishing. For clarity in the remainder of this article, where both appear the father will be called the Wounded King, the son the Fisher King.

It isn't wrong but there is so much more and so many more interpretations available in history alone, let alone variations in fiction produced since the 12th century.

For a bit of scholastic background which may at least give you some history to work from, I recommend the [Camelot Project at the University of Rochester](http://www.lib.rochester.edu/camelot/Fisherking/fkessay.htm) and their Fisher King reference section online.